# Prestashop Webservices - Property OrderDetail->product_price is empty on order creation

Tags: web-services, prestashop

I'm trying to create orders thanks to Prestashop WebServices. I successfully created Customers, Addresses and Carts but Order creation is crashing. Here is the error I get using the following curl request :

```
curl -i -X POST -d @tmpOrder.text http://secretKey@localhost:8888/api/orders
```

> Property OrderDetail->product_price is empty

Here are the XML files I use to create my cart (and trying to create my order.

tmpCart.text

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<cart>
        <id></id>
    <id_address_delivery>6</id_address_delivery>
    <id_address_invoice>6</id_address_invoice>
    <id_currency>1</id_currency>
    <id_customer>2</id_customer>
    <id_guest></id_guest>
    <id_lang>1</id_lang>
    <id_shop_group>1</id_shop_group>
    <id_shop>1</id_shop>
    <id_carrier>2</id_carrier>
    <recyclable></recyclable>
    <gift></gift>
    <gift_message></gift_message>
    <mobile_theme></mobile_theme>
    <delivery_option></delivery_option>
    <secure_key></secure_key>
    <allow_seperated_package></allow_seperated_package>
    <date_add></date_add>
    <date_upd></date_upd>
<associations>
<cart_rows>
    <cart_row>
    <id_product>2</id_product>
    <product_price>26.999852</product_price>
    <id_product_attribute>1</id_product_attribute>
    <id_address_delivery>6</id_address_delivery>
    <quantity>2</quantity>
    </cart_row>
</cart_rows>
</associations>
</cart>
</prestashop>
```

tmpOrder.txt

```
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<order>
        <id></id>
        <id_address_delivery>6</id_address_delivery>
        <id_address_invoice>6</id_address_invoice>
        <id_cart>42</id_cart>
        <id_currency>1</id_currency>
        <id_lang>1</id_lang>
        <id_customer>2</id_customer>
        <id_carrier>2</id_carrier>
        <current_state>1</current_state>
        <module>cheque</module>
        <payment>Chèque</payment>
        <total_paid>1</total_paid>
        <total_paid_real>54</total_paid_real>
        <total_products>2</total_products>
        <total_products_wt>54</total_products_wt>
        <conversion_rate>1</conversion_rate>
        <reference></reference>
<associations>
<order_rows>
        <order_row>
        <id></id>
        <product_id>2</product_id>
        <product_attribute_id>1</product_attribute_id>
        <product_quantity>2</product_quantity>
        <product_name>TEST</product_name>
        <product_reference></product_reference>
        <product_ean13></product_ean13>
        <product_upc></product_upc>
        <product_price>26.999852</product_price>
        <unit_price_tax_incl>26.999852</unit_price_tax_incl>
        <unit_price_tax_excl>26.999852</unit_price_tax_excl>
</order_row>
</order_rows>
</associations>
</order>
</prestashop>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found out what is wrong. It seems that the `product_attribute_id` of my product was wrong. Therefore, it was looking for an inexistent price in the prices array.